# Scalar multiplication with projective coordinates

Tags: elliptic-curves, nist

I'm implementing point addition, doubling and scalar multiplication using projective coordinates. I took reference from [this link](https://web.archive.org/web/20160405053025/https://www.nsa.gov/ia/_files/nist-routines.pdf).

I have implemented

- Routine 2.2.6 (ec_double)
- Routine 2.2.7 (ec_add)
- Routine 2.2.8 (ec_full_add)
- Routine 2.2.9 (ecc_full_sub)

They all are working and I have verified the results with the example results given at the last for P-256 curve.

I implemented Routine 2.2.10 ec_mul t(Scalar multiplication) But I couldnt get the correct output. In line 15 and 16 of this routine they take the binary representation of $d$ (random number) and $3d$. And the loop skips both MSB and LSB and performs the operations.

I got doubts like that $3d$ is modular multiplication or simple multiplication?. The loops runs for $d$ or $3d$ if its not modular multiplication?

Is there anything else I'm missing out?. If somebody has followed this algorithm and implemented it please help me out here.

Comment: I have problems with ec_doubling. It gives wrong result. E.g. for point (5,1) it gives result (11,4) it should be (6,3). Are you sure there is no mistake in formula?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3d multiplication is a simple multiplication not a mod multiplication.

I suggest you to check [IEEE Std 1363-2000](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/iel5/7168/19282/00891000.pdf) document and "A.10.3 Elliptic scalar multiplication" part of that document if you can.
It has somewhat more explanation than Nist's document.

Comment: If it is not modulo mul, 3d will have an extra byte than d. Then how does the loop work? Line 17 says the loop runs from l-1 to 1. This is meant for d or 3d?. And I don't have access to the reference document which u suggested

Comment: I managed to get a look into the document u suggested. The one i'm using is in A.10.9 . In that algorithm k(random number) and 3k are used. 3K will have one byte extra than k and the loop runs for i form l-1 to 1. How exactly will it satisfy for both h[i] and k[i] because h will contain one byte extra than k.

Comment: @abejoe yeah A.10.3 gives a more generalized function whereas A.10.9 provides scalar multiplication algorithm for projective coordinates. In the algorithms l is the most significant bit index of 3d(note that index number start from 0). In each case, because the loop starts from l-1, you dont have to worry about one extra bit. Both h[] and k[] arrays have elements with index "l-1" (i mean h[l-1] and k[l-1] are valid). I dont know the mathematical detail behind it, but that algorithm should work without taking into account the MSB of 3d.

Comment: Since its for P-256 the random number 'k' will have only 256 bits and 3k will contain 260 bits. This difference causes all the doubts. The loop's i starts from l-1 of 3k or k, because in this case both are different. l-1 will start from 259th bit of 3k(assuming 260th bit is set) but then d has only 256 bits.

Comment: @abejoe Considering that 4d is a two bit shift of d, 3d would have at most 2 more bits than d. Also, note that d is less than base point order

Comment: @abejoe On the other hand, i dont understand what is bothering you. Did you implemented the algorithm and got the wrong result in a test case, or are you questioning the algorithm? If, it is the second case, i cant help you but in the first case i can ensure you that it works correctly.

Comment: Imagine d=698 and 3d is 2094. In binary form 698 is 0110 1001 1000 and 2094 is 0010 0000 1001 0100 . Now 'L' of '3d' is '1' of ' 0010 ' which is 14th bit. Hence ' L-1' is 0 which is 13th bit. But d has only 12 bits. Am i anywhere wrong in understanding?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35807/discussion-between-abejoe-and-makif).